# SQL statement to insert record based on the Case result

Tags: sql, oracle

I have internal system which uses parameters and front-end.
So, here is the conundrum:

1. When record is updated, the trigger is fired and SQL statement is executed.
2. I need to check if the field contain word "BAD" or "GOOD" and my SQL statement must be different. And I can't use stored procedures. must be pure SQL

something like this

```
CASE
  WHEN  (TO_CHAR(?)=TO_CHAR('GOOD')) 
     THEN INSERT VALUES INTO GOOD_TABLE
  WHEN  (TO_CHAR(?)=TO_CHAR('BAD')) 
     THEN INSERT VALUES INTO BAD_TABLE
END
```

Comment: Different how? Can you show the difference because simply inserting a different value is another thing than using a completey different query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage the multi-table inserts functionality using INSERT FIRST / INSERT ALL command, as below:

```
   INSERT FIRST
   WHEN (TO_CHAR(?)='GOOD') THEN
      INTO GOOD_TABLE
         VALUES(values...)
   WHEN (TO_CHAR(?)='BAD') THEN
      INTO BAD_TABLE
         VALUES(values...)
   SELECT values, ?
   FROM mytable;
```

**Reference**:

[Multi table Inserts on Oracle Examples blog](http://oracleexamples.wordpress.com/2009/08/11/some-multi-table-inserts/) (Very good examples)